# Generating unique random numbers from 10000000 to 99999999

Tags: php, random

I need to create unique random pins using numbers only. I need to produce between 10,000,000 and 99,999,999. I need to create 100,000 pins

Here's the code I am currently using:

```
function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}
print_r( UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(10000000,99999999,100000));
```

This code still runs okay with my server using 50000 but not with 100000 items. Can you help me, is there code that can produce this many unique numbers without using too much memory in the server?

Comment: You can generate randomize the amount of digits first and then randomize a number between 0-9 that amount of times

Comment: Get rid of the memory overhead of `$numbers = range($min, $max);` for a start. Create each rand individually, test if it's already in a results array, until you've reached your quantity

Comment: http://www.php.net/mt_rand

Comment: you can split your numbers : min and max, and when you generate the randoms you concatenate them.

Comment: But if you have to store large volumes of data in memory, it will use lots of memory, and the more you increase those volumes the more memory you'll need.... sounds obvious, and it is.... so you should ask why you really need an array with 100000 random numbers in memory at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick for you:

```
<?php
    function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
        $i = 0;
        $numbers = array();
        while( $i <= $quantity ){
            $numbers[$i] = mt_rand($min, $max);
            $i++;
        }
        print_r( $numbers );
    }
    UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(10000000,99999999,100000);   
?>
```

As of the comment to my answer, there is a posibility of multiple keys containing the same pin.
This code will eliminate duplicates, but takes a lot more computing time:

```
<?php
    function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
        $i = 0;
        $numbers = array();
        while( $i <= $quantity ){
            $number = mt_rand( $min, $max );
            if( !in_array( $number, $numbers ) ){
                $numbers[$i] = $number;
                $i++;
            }           
        }
        print_r( $numbers );
    }
    UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(10000000,99999999,100000);   
?>
```

Comment: Edited my answer to contain the posibility of avoiding duplicates.

Comment: It may be more efficient to assign `$numbers[$number] = true;` and `return array_keys($numbers);` - I'm not certain, but I'm fairly sure that `isset($numbers[$number])` is a much faster check than `in_array($number,$numbers)`.

Answer (score 0):

Small idea; do a range($min, $quantity) and then multiply all generated numbers by $max / $quantity. This would drastically reduce your $numbers array and still have the correct range.

```
function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range(0, $quantity);
    shuffle($numbers);
    array_walk($numbers, function(&$value, $key, $params) {
        $value = floor($params[0] + $value * ($params[1]-$params[0]) / $params[2]);
    }, array($min, $max, $quantity));
    return $numbers;
}
print_r( UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange(10000000,99999999,100000));
```

Comment: Not sure about speed, but you at least wont have to to two cascaded loops to check uniqueness on all results.

Comment: Thanks Sir, but it just giving me a white screen, its not running.

Comment: fixed. A math genius might want to look over it, but it seems correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

The `range()` uses just to much memory; you generate an array of 90,000,000 `int` values, each 8 bytes big on your 64 bit machine. This makes it an 686 MB array.

So we need to generate every number on its own and check, if it's already in your result array (to ensure, every number is unique)

```
function UniqueRandomNumbersWithinRange($min, $max, $quantity) {
    if ($max - $min < $quantity * 10) return false;

    $unique_numbers = array();
    while (count($unique_numbers) < $quantity) {
        $random_number = mt_rand($min, $max);
        if (!in_array($random_number, $unique_numbers)) $unique_numbers[] = mt_rand($min, $max);
    }
    return $unique_numbers;
}
```

The first line inside the function checks, if there are enough numbers between `$min` and `$max` available, to generate `$quantity` unique numbers; otherwise we get an infinite loop here. I added a factor of 10, so there is some space for randomness ;)